# Анимированный текст с волной

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

### Как это работает

Представленное ниже изображение `.png` обрезается  текстом с анимацией.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Образец в действии:

```css
body { background: #000000; }

.Wave-Loader {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 100pt;
 text-align: center;
 height: 120px;
 line-height: 110px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 100px;
 bottom: 0;
}

.Wave-Loader.Wave {
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/uFpLbYt.png");
 -moz-background-clip: text;
 -o-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
 animation: Wave-Loader 1s infinite linear;
 background-size: 200px 100px;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes Wave-Loader {
 0% { background-position: 0 bottom; }
 100% { background-position: 200px bottom; }
}
```

```html
<div class="Wave-Loader Wave">loading</div>
```

### Вопрос

Вместо того, чтобы использовать изображение, как я могу заменить только форму CSS, поскольку я хотел бы реализовать свою анимацию цвета, которая изменит цвет белой волны, которую вы видите в моей демонстрации выше, от красного до зеленого.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Черный фон используется только для `StackOverflow`, тогда как мой фон может отличаться по цвету.

### Примеры волнового эффекта

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #000000;
}
#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: -5px;
  top: 40px;
}
#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000000;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave"></div>
```

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:red;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Animated text with CSS wave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41426043/7394871) от участника  [@Tim Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6410837/tim-marshall).</sub>

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41426043/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти тот же эффект можно достичь на css3

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0mJK.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation: wave 6s infinite alternate;
  animation: wave 6s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave {
  0% {
    background-position: left 0 top 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 1000px top 0;
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    background-position: left 0 top 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 1000px top 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>wave effect</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Вы можете достичь, **заполнение текста анимированной волной**,  несколькими методами:

Ниже приведено решение  `SVG` с использованием элемента `pattern`.
 Текст заполняется волнообразным узором, а рисунок анимирован с анимацией `SMIL`.

*Вот как это выглядит:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой подход позволит  заполнить `pattern` не простым фоном (например, градиентом), а также  позволит отобразить текст поверх изображения или любого несимметричного фона.

Вы можете видеть это в действии здесь: [Анимированная волна, обрезанная с текстом.](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YNKMpB)

```css
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
body{
  background:url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
svg{font-weight:bold;max-width:600px;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 20">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#326384"/>
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#123752"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="wave" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path id="wavePath" d="M-40 9 Q-30 7 -20 9 T0 9 T20 9 T40 9 T60 9 T80 9 T100 9 T120 9 V20 H-40z" fill="url(#gradient)"> 
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" from="0,0" to="40,0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </path>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="15" font-size="17" fill="url(#wave)"  fill-opacity="0.6">LOADING</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="15" font-size="17" fill="url(#gradient)" fill-opacity="0.1">LOADING</text>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Animated text with CSS wave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41430024/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Что-то похожее так же можно сделать градиентами:

```css
span {
  --h: 50px;
  font-size: calc(var(--h) * 2);
  --r: 35px;
  --dy: 25px;
  --c: steelblue;
  animation: flow 1s linear infinite;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle at 50px calc(var(--h) + var(--dy)), var(--c) var(--r), #0000    calc(1px + var(--r))), 
   radial-gradient(circle at 50px calc(    -1   * var(--dy)), #0000    var(--r), var(--c) calc(1px + var(--r)));
  background-size: calc(var(--h) * 2) calc(var(--h));
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #0003;
  padding-top: 10px
}

@keyframes flow {
  from {background-position: 0     0, 50px  var(--h)}
  to   {background-position: 100px 0, 150px var(--h)}
}
```

```html
<span>1234567890</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с использованием `clip-path`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.block {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block__title {
  font-size: 14vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block__title:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: rgba(88, 114, 133, .5);
}

.block__title:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: rgba(88, 114, 133, 1);
  animation: animTextWave 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animTextWave {
  0%,
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 55%, 10% 50%, 25% 45%, 35% 45%, 45% 50%, 60% 55%, 75% 60%, 85% 60%, 90% 55%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 10% 55%, 20% 61%, 31% 65%, 44% 63%, 56% 56%, 67% 52%, 76% 46%, 88% 42%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1 class="block__title">Loading</h1>
  <h1 class="block__title">Loading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT если ответ понраввился больше чем мой - переизбери - тут это практикуется часто

Comment: @Alexandr_TT - Я даю ответы не ради баллов. может кому-то в будущем пригодиться

Answer (score 3):

Вариант CSS. Без использования картинок. На градиентах.

*Сделано на скорую руку, можно конечно еще чище.*

```css
body {
  background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 90vh;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 60px 90px, rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.3) 120px, #4f6a7d 120px);
  background-size: 120px 400px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: background 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Loading</h1>
```